# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch` | React store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm building an application to drop files and refresh a table, the `pushFile` event gets triggered when I drop the file on a specific zone, I'm using a `dispatch` function to push the file to a reducer, and the reducer look at the `case` and push the file into `dataRows` array in the store, I'm also using some `checkboxes` to filter the data, I push these filters to the reducer using a `dispatch` function as well,
my main problem is how to initialize the store and give it a default value in this part of the code: 
As of now I'm passing `null` as you can see in this line :
`const store = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);`
I tried to pass `initialState` object, but it didn't let me do it and gave me an error

> Argument of type '{ state: { searchFilter: string[]; dataRows: DataRow[]; }; dispatch: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContextType'.
>     Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.
>       Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<{ type: string; value: unknown; }>'

**I want a way to create an instance of `dispatch` that I can assign to dispatch.** 
Or any other solution that let me refactor my reducer, so it doesn't need to have a `dispatch` in the store, but how I'm going to expose it to be used in the `DropZone` ?

```js
const initialState = {
  state : {
    searchFilter: initFilter,
    dataRows: initDataRows
  },
  dispatch: null
};


interface ContextType {
    state: {
      searchFilter: string[];
      dataRows: DataRow[];
    };
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<{ type: string; value: unknown }>;
  };



const store = createContext<ContextType | null>(null);
```

```js
const StateProvider = ( { children} : any ) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state : any, action:{type:string, value:any}) => {
    console.log("I'm inside reducer hey hey hey");
    console.log("state : ", state);
    switch(action.type) {
        case "dateChecked": 
            //console.log("dateChecked: ", action.value);
            if(state.searchFilter && state.searchFilter.includes(action.value)){
                const searchFilter = state.searchFilter.filter((v: string) => v !== action.value);
                const newState = { ...state, searchFilter };
                //state.searchFilter = newSearchFilter;
                return newState;
            }else{
                state.searchFilter.push(action.value);
            }  
        break;
        case "dataIssueChecked":
          console.log("dataIssueChecked: ", action.value);
            if(state.searchFilter.includes(action.value)){
                let searchFilter = state.searchFilter.filter((v: string) => v !== action.value);
                const newState = { ...state, searchFilter };
                return newState;
            }else{
                state.searchFilter.push(action.value);
            }
        break;
        case "UPDATE_TABLE":
            console.log("UPDATE_TABLE in store scope : ", action.value);
            console.log("state : ", state);
            console.log("state.dataRows : ", state.dataRows);
            state.dataRows =  action.value;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error();
    };
  }, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the `dispatch` property in the original version optional ? `interface MyContext { dispatch?: React.Dispatch<{ type: string; value: unknown }>; }`. Then you simply _omit_ `dispatch` from `initialState` and happily call `createContext(initialState)`

Comment: I did what you mentioned and that fixed the error, but I got another error while I was trying to invoke `dispatch` in another component `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2722`  `<ListItem button key={text} onClick={ () => store.dispatch(action("dateChecked", text))}>`

Comment: Is the compiler not telling us something true however? Since you don't specify an initial value for dispatch, it may not be present.

Comment: it's a tricky situation, I have been trying to solve it for hours.

Comment: The following is correct and will type check, but there may be better options: `<ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => store?.dispatch(action("dateChecked", text))}>`

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? it's still throwing this error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`

Comment: Yes, it is supprted since ts 3.7. Alternately write `() => store.dispatch && store?.dispatch(action("dateChecked", text))`, or use a block body w/ `if`, or extract a variable, etc.

Comment: I ended up using `// @ts-ignore` to make it work